# Use CSS to alternate ul bullet point styles

Tags: css, html-lists

I would like to alternate list-style-type properties for ul lists, so that the outer is a disc, then one inner ul list is a circle, than one more inner is a disc, and so on.

Essentially, what I want is this:

```html
<ul><!-- use disc -->
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>
    <ul><!-- use circle -->
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>
        <ul><!-- use disc -->
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

How would I accomplish this using CSS?

Comment: Is the number of nesting levels fixed? Because if not, it will be pretty difficult to accomplish this with CSS alone.

Comment: No, I am attempting to repeat list-style-type for an list that can be as long as possible, though if need be, I may manually code-in indenting levels, if there is other solution. If a JavaScript solution works, that is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this...

```css
li { list-style: circle; }
li li { list-style: disc; }
li li li { list-style: square; }
```

And so on...

The first level of list items will have the "circle" type marker. The second (embedded) will use "discs". The third level will use squares.

Simply take the above CSS and change the `list-style` to suit your needs. You can find a list of `list-style` types here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: That doesn't work; you get two bullets after the first li, with my example code. In addition, your bullet styles don't continue repeating the same pattern of list-style.

Answer (score 4):

You could use separate styles by adding `class` or `id` to the `ul` tags:

```html
<ul class="disk"><!-- use disk -->
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="circle"><!-- use circle -->
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>
        <ul class="disk"><!-- use disk -->
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.disk
{
    list-style-type: disc;
}

.circle
{
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Or you could add styles to `ul`s depending on how they are nested:

```css
ul
{
    list-style-type:disc;
}

ul li ul
{
    list-style-type:circle;
}

ul li ul li ul
{
    list-style-type:disc;
}
```

Off the top of my head, so there might be some minor errors, but both these examples should basically work.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to give each element with different bullet type a class name.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="disk">test</li>
    <li class="circle">test</li>
    <li class="sq">test</li>
    <li class="sq">test</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.disk {    
    list-style-type: disc;
}
.circle {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
.sq {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LWQrh/

Comment: What I need, though, is for bullets to switch while being embedded within other `li` elements.

Comment: You can't do that. you need to reference each level of your `ul` or `li`'s with a class name. Otherwise you will have double or triple bullets depending on how deep your tree is.

Comment: Is it possible to use CSS3 selectors for browsers that support them, and use ids for browsers that don't support them?

Comment: That's being redundant, No reason to use css3 if you are using id's.

Comment: Would it be possible using PHP or JavaScript to automatically generate lists with the correct ids?

Comment: Downvoted - you [should not name CSS styles based on visual appearance](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason why I get double bullets. My lists are not semantically correct, so they are creating multiple bullets.

This is the proper HTML:

```html
<ul><!-- use disc -->
  <li>Lorem ipsum
    <ul><!-- use circle -->
      <li>Lorem ipsum
        <ul><!-- use disc -->
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

With the fixed code, the solutions above work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this one is no, it cannot be accomplished through CSS in a consistent manner.

You could write some javascript to parse through the page and basically maintain a stack of ULs, but it would be kind of sloppy and hackish. It'd have to be something like this.

```
function doStyle(htmlBlock, depth)
    var returnHtml = '';

    // While the HTML block presented has UL tags within it
    while(htmlBlock.indexOf('<ul>') > 0) {

        // Take all the content up to the next/first <UL>
        returnHtml += htmlBlock.substring(0, htmlBlock.indexOf('<ul>'));

        // Add a styled <UL>, alternating on depth
        returnHtml += '<ul class="' + (depth % 2 == 0 ? 'square' : 'circle') + '">';

        // Recurse on the content inside that UL, using depth + 1
        returnHtml += doStyle(htmlBlock.substring(htmlBlock.indexOf('<ul>'), htmlBlock.indexOf('</ul>')), depth + 1);

        // Close the <UL>
        returnHtml += '</ul>';

        // Pull the whole UL block out of the remaining string
        htmlBlock = htmlBlock.substring(htmlBlock.indexOf('</ul>') + 5);
    }

    // Return the built up string, 
    // And whatever is left of the original HTML block
    return returnHtml + htmlBlock;
}
```